# Singular values of random matrices with inhomogeneous variances

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices

If $X$ is a random rectangular matrix with independent identically distributed entries of zero mean and equal variance, then as $X$ gets big its singular values tend to a [Marchenko-Pastur distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution). What if the entries have different variances?

Specifically, let the variance of all entries in row $n$ be $V_n$, where $V_n$ is drawn from a fixed probability density $p(V)$ independently for each row; and the entries in row $n$ are conditionally independent given $V_n$. What distribution do the singular values of $X$ follow as the matrix gets big?

We can assume any particular distribution for the variances and the entries if that helps.

Comment: If you assume that the variance of each entry is drawn indepdently from $p(V)$, then you have an effective variance for the entries and the MP law applies. However in your setup, there is a coupling between the entries of a row, so the matrix entries are no longer i.i.d.

Comment: That's right! The question is whether there are any practical methods for computing the singular value distribution in this case. Looking at the literature (including Marcenko and Pastur's original paper) it seems like this might be doable with a Stieltjes Transform. But any examples I came up with all ran into horrible integrals.